# The meaning of "all the hair" in the novel 'Human Stain'

Tags: meaning-in-context

I am living in Seoul, and reading a novel, Human Stain.  I found this sentence in it:

> Under the protection of Pierce Roberts, the handsome young hotshot president with **all the hair** who came in and appointed him  to the deanship-and who told him...

I know "hair" usually means the stuff that grows out of your head, but it seems strange here-- I don't understand why hair would be mentioned, or what "all of it" would mean.  Is there another meaning of "hair" in America that I don't understand?

Comment: Is there any context before this that describes Pierce Roberts? Does he have a lot of hair?

Comment: You'd added some punctuation that wasn't present in the original.  Take care not to do that.

Comment: The example contains "who came in who came in". I assume that this is a typo?

Comment: I edited the question to include the reason you are asking it, which you wrote in a comment below.  I hope this will help you obtain better answers, and also prevent the question from being closed.

Answer (score 2):

It's an idiomatic usage reflected in...

> *But the man [**with all the beard**](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22the%20man%20with%20all%20the%20beard%22) was already clambering up on the nearest table...*
> *We can dig that, says the girl [**with all the hair**](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22says%20the%20girl%20with%20all%20the%20hair%22).*

...where *the X with all the Y* essentially means that ***X*** has ***a lot of, and/or very noticeable Y***.

I can't find a written example, but I personally would be fine with *I like the look of that **girl with all the eyes** over there*. Identifying a girl with very noticeable (large, khol-enhanced?) eyes.

Comment: This could be regarded as a variant of "all that," as in "all that junk / up in your trunk."

Answer (score 0):

Without any reason to think otherwise, I'd assume this is just the stuff that grows on people's heads.

It is just making a point that Roberts is still young and not (yet) bald. Perhaps this makes a comparison to the other professors who are old and bald.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I just guess there may be other meanings for the word of 'hair' in America.

Comment: Or maybe he has long or unusually thick hair.